# jQuery: Iterating over children and boolean values

Tags: jquery, boolean, each

If each .itemToFilter children in the parent td fails the test (thus returning all TRUE), then alert('hello world') should be executed. But it's not!

The first IF statement is working correctly and I have tested it with alerts. But not the second one.

```
var businessTypePullDownValue = $('.businessTypePullDown').val();

$('.businessTypeRow td').each( function() {

    var foundOne = $(this).children('.itemToFilter').each( function() {                

        if(($(this).attr('value') == businessTypePullDownValue)) {
            return true; 
        }
    });

    if(!foundOne) {
        alert('hello world');
    }

});​
```

Comment: please provide the source html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Returning `true` within `each` simply continues to the next iteration.  You will need to do something like this:

```
var foundOne = false;

$(this).children('.itemToFilter').each( function() {                

    if(($(this).attr('value') == businessTypePullDownValue)) {
        foundOne = true;
        return false;  // break the loop
    }
});

if(!foundOne) {
    alert('hello world');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.businessTypeRow td').each( function() {
    // get child element which class is itemToFilter and
    // value equals to businessTypePullDownValue
    var $elements = $('.itemToFilter[value="' + businessTypePullDownValue + '"]', this);

    if($elements.length > 0) {
        alert('Hello world');
    }
});
```